# lit until rendering function source

Tags: typescript, lit

I am facing a weird problem, I am using lit `until` to wait for a promise to return the template, however the the until's function code is rendered instead,
For ex, I have ,

```
render() {
    return html`
      <div class="small-tool-card">
        ${this.renderProductLogo(product)}
        <div class="text-container">
          ${this.renderProductTitle(product)}
          ${until(
            this.renderTryLink(product),
            html`
              loading...
            `
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    `;
  }
```

and instead of "loading..." or the output of renderTryLink(), which returns a promise that resolves to html`` , I see the following code being rendered,

```
(part) => { let state = _state.get(part); if (state === undefined) { state = { lastRenderedIndex: _infinity, values: [], }; _state.set(part, state); } const previousValues
```

any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

changing

```
import { until } from 'lit-html/directives/until.js';
```

to

```
import { until } from 'lit/directives/until.js';
```

solved this. I believe by specifically importing from lit-html, we were missing other directives. Note that the [example code on lit](https://lit.dev/docs/v1/lit-html/template-reference/#until) needs to be fixed as well.